# How to select and copy text from TextBox of webView in Android?

Tags: android, html, webview, android-webview

I need to select text from `WebView`. But the text which I need to select belongs to `TextBox` (`EditText`) in the website in `WebView`. When I open that web page in other browsers (crome, firefox) in PC and mobile, then I am able to select and copy text from TextBox.

It looks like `WebView` of android does not provide all functionalities which are provided by other browsers.

So why I am not able to select and copy text from TextBox in WebView. What is the solution for this problem?

This is my webview code.

```
 webView = (WebView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.webview);
                    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
                    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
                    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                                                   @Override
                                                   public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                                                       super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
                                                   }
                                               }
                    );
                  /*  webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                                                 @Override
                                                 public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
                                                     super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
                                                 }
                                             }
                    );*/

                    webView.loadUrl(msg);

                    emulateShiftHeld(webView);
```

And this function responsible for select and copy functionality in webview.

```
private void emulateShiftHeld(WebView view)
    {
        try
        {
            Method m = WebView.class.getMethod("emulateShiftHeld", null);
            m.invoke(this, null);

            KeyEvent shiftPressEvent = new KeyEvent(0, 0, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                    KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT, 0, 0);
            shiftPressEvent.dispatch(view);
            Toast.makeText(this, "select_text_now", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("dd", "Exception in emulateShiftHeld()", e);
        }
    }
```

And this is the code of Textbox in website

```
 <input type="text" value="But I am not able to select and copy this this text because this text belongs to TextBox" readonly="">
```

[image: img]